# typecript promise return type asynchronous function

Tags: typescript

I have this asynchronous function and am trying to return an object or null.

But I get an error in defining the type.

How to define this data type?

```
const checkIsValidConnection = async (number: string): Promise<string | null> => {
  const defaultConnection = await GetDefaultConnection();

  const wbot = getWbot(defaultConnection.id);

  const contactId = await wbot.getNumberId(`${number}`);

  return contactId;
};

export default checkIsValidConnection;
```

> Type 'ContactId | null' is not assignable to type 'string | null'.
> Type 'ContactId' is not assignable to type 'string'.

[image]

Comment: The error is pretty clear, you are trying to assign `contactId` which is apparently not a string to a string return value. Check the signature for `wbot.getNumberId` and see what it's returning (number?).

Comment: `    export interface ContactId {
        server: string,
        user: string,
        _serialized: string,
    }`

Try change the string with this interface.

I believe that the ContactId is an object with these 3 fields, so u should declare it correctly

Comment: the type of `contactId` is an object, but honestly, I tried to use other types and I am unable to succeed.

Comment: But the compiler is actually detecting it to be `WAWEBJS.ContactID`

https://github.com/pedroslopez/whatsapp-web.js/blob/master/index.d.ts

This is the beauty of TypeScript.

Comment: @Darkripper Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're working with
https://github.com/pedroslopez/whatsapp-web.js/blob/master/index.d.ts

which indicates `WAWEBJS.ContactID` to be an interface of the following.

```
interface ContactId { server: string, user: string, _serialized: string}
```

You should update the return type of your promise to either this `interface` or stick to the `WAWEBJS.ContactID`